# logs of Ec2Client calls from AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

My web app makes calls to [start](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html#startInstances(software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.StartInstancesRequest)) and [stop](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html#stopInstances(software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.StopInstancesRequest)) AWS EC2 instances using the AWS SDK for Java via an [Ec2Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html). Do these calls get logged anywhere within AWS?

I looked at the System Manager logs and I don't see any record of these commands logged there. I also can't find an AWS CLI command that would display them. The only way I know of so far to verify the commands were sent successfully is to check whether the instances started or stopped as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs of AWS API calls like that would be in [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html).

Comment: That definitely looks promising. Do you know how the "Event name" would show up for Ec2Client commands? I see lots of "UpdateInstanceInformation" events, but nothing thus far that identifies my start or stop instance commands among those.

Comment: I seem to have found these as CreateStack and DeleteStack events in CloudTrail Event history. What's strange is I believe my API sent startInstances and stopInstances commands, yet those don't appear in the event history. I think the answer is correct, though, in that the activity does seem to have been captured in CloudTrail, just in a confounding way.

Comment: `CreateStack` and `DeleteStack` are CloudFormation API calls, not EC2 API calls. Those are not related to your API calls. You said earlier in a deleted comment that you saw the EC2 API calls. Are you now saying you were wrong and didn't see them?

Comment: Yes, I was indeed initially wrong about seeing them. I saw StartInstance and StopInstance events for other processes, which I had mistaken for what I was looking for - hence the deleted comment. Still looking further. The event names for Ec2 start and stop instance commands should show up in CloudTrail as StartInstance or StopInstance (or the -s versions of those), correct?

Comment: That's correct.